# Filepath from NSFileHandle on iOS (Swift or Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfilehandle

I got `NSFileHandle` from a function call and would like to access the file it refers to. How to get it?

I know that the resource might have multiple file paths or no file path at all (file in memory). However, it would be nice to get anything :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `F_GETPATH`:

```
NSFileHandle* Handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:
                            @"/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist"];
char Path[MAXPATHLEN];
if (Handle && fcntl([Handle fileDescriptor], F_GETPATH, Path) != -1)
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:Path]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift:

```
var buffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(MAXPATHLEN))
_  = fcntl(fileHandle.fileDescriptor, F_GETPATH, &buffer)
let fileName = String(cString: buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to find this information if you *really* want to. The
>   fstat() call will give you the device and inode number of the file, if
>   it has one. You can then search that device for a file with that
>   inode. But this will be slow, and again it might not even exist.

[source](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/234220-path-from-nsfilehandle.html#234222)